# Prove that $\Sigma a_\nu = \Sigma b_\nu$ (Remmert, exercise 2, section 1 chapter 0)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I'm studying Complex analysis from Remmert Theory of Complex Functions book and I'm trying to do the exercises. However, I'm stuck with exercise 2, section 1, chapter 0. It says:

Let $a_1,...,a_n, b_1,...b_n\in \mathbb{C}$ and satisfy $\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} a^j_\nu=\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} b^j_\nu$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there is a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,...n\}$ such that $a_\nu=b_{\pi(\nu)}$ for all $\nu \in \{1,..., n\}.$

I tried to see $\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} a^j_\nu=\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} b^j_\nu$ as a polynomial of $2n$ variables like $p(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)= \sum_{\nu=1}^{n} x^j_\nu - y^j_\nu$ and express it like product of its roots. However, I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials, and I do not know where to use it!.

I'm so confused in this exercise. I will apreciate all your help!

Comment: A complex analysis argument is what is expected. Try to find a holomorphic function where these sums occur as the coefficients in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: another idea is to use Newton's relations to show that the symmetric sums are equal, so both sets of numbers roots of the same degree $n$ polynomial